Is it possible to have a crystal structure where you are getting peaks of different intensities at different $2\theta$ values with same $hkl$ planes?
Is it possible to have a crystal structure. where you are getting peaks of different intensities at different 2thetha values with same h k l planes? What will you be calling that system to be a single crystal or a polycrystal?
for example I am getting 211 (hkl) peak for different 2thetha values in the pxrd.

if you have one wavelength and one crystal, you get one peak for given hkl
